# power bi scheduled refresh automatically disabled

Tags: powerbi

I have scheduled 8 refreshes in Power BI for a day for 7 dashboards. But i found out that one of the dashboards is not updating its values. That particular dashboard only refreshes if refresh now option is clicked. Also the schedule refresh option is disabled automatically every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to troubleshoot why your one dashboard refresh is failing.  Follow the steps [recommended here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/configure-scheduled-refresh#viewing-the-status-of-schedule-refresh-plan):

1. Go to the Power Bi Web Portal and browse to the location of your dashboard.
2. Right click on the the three dots and select Manage
3. In the left menu select "Scheduled Refresh" tab (see left red circle in image)

[image]

4. The rightmost column **Status** will contain any error that was occurred (see right circle from above image).

The [documentation on configuring Scheduled Refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-scheduled-refresh) can be a good place to find a solution to the cause of your problems as well as this [scheduled refresh troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/scheduled-refresh-troubleshoot).  Without the error, we can only guess that its an authentication error, problem with data source, gateway, drivers, memory, etc.

Comment: okay. The data source looks to be working good. and refresh has been successful for now.Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 5):

Just sharing my learning on the same issue. I have just found out through technical support that schedule refresh will turn off automatically after 4 refresh fails.
I couldn't find the reason because my schedule was being turned off randomly. So it seems that's the reason. I have few sources connected and every time one is down my refresh fails.